# How to compose Outlook email through batch file

Tags: batch-file, outlook

I am trying to open up outlook, fill the `To: Subject: and Body:` of the mail through batch file.

This is my file:

```
set compose=/c ipm.note

set subject=some thing
set body=some body
set recipients=/m "recipient@example.com&subject=%subject%&body=%body%"

rem attachment done
set attachment=/a "h.txt"

start "Outlook" "OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle /profile "GRP" %compose% %recipients% %attachment%
```

When running this file I get outlook error saying `"The command line argument is not valid . Verify the switch you are using"`

Pls help

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? IIRC some versions do not allow both /c and /a

Comment: Outlook 2016....

Comment: Even /c /m  is not working ... only /c and /a individually and together work